# How to define a compound operator in Ruby (e.g. +=)?

Tags: ruby, operators

So, I am trying to define the operators `+` and `+=` for a Ruby class and I try:

```
class A
    def +(x)
    end

    def +=(x)
    end
end
```

Ruby likes the `+` but not the `+=`, giving me this error:

> syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' or '\n'

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `a += b` === `a = a + b`, no?

Comment: Semantically, yes. Ruby (1.9.3, btw) does not like the operator method syntax, however, which I thought would be acceptable, just like such is defined for Fixnums, Strings, and Arrays.

Comment: @xuinkrbin. There is no `+=` method for any of those classes, or any class in Ruby for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot overload the assignment operators in ruby

[Overloading Operators - Ruby](http://ruby.about.com/od/oo/ss/Overloading-Operators.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Your `a += b` is interpreted as `a = a + b` and only `+` operator is used. You have not to define `+=` operator also